# Boot custom linux up by pressing Lenovo OKR button?

Tags: linux, lenovo-laptop, system-restore

I have a Lenovo Y510p laptop and I'm a Linux user, use Windows only for gaming. The device had no OS when I bought it and I also installed an SSD besides the 1TB hard drive.

I would like to "hack" the One-Key-Recovery button, because I have no interest in its default behaviour (I don't need Windows recovery), but if I could boot up a hidden, fail-safe Linux with it, that would be great. How could I achieve it? I tried to search what the button does, but I only found some installers for Windows that could magically create a partition for the recovery. I would like to override this behaviour completely to boot up something else.

Edit, more info:

> After installing the official software it creates a custom partition with the mirror of the OS and its settings or something like that. And then pressing the OKR button instead of the normal power button, it boots from that partition and starts the recovery program (without loading the full OS). It works something like this, but I have not tried it. I'm afraid it is too tied to Windows.

Comment: I have some ideas which you could try but I do not have a solution up my sleeve. First of all what IS the default behaviour. What is it supposed to do? Do you know how it works on win?

Comment: After installing the official software it creates a custom partition with the mirror of the OS and its settings or something like that. And then pressing the OKR button instead of the normal power button, it boots from that partition and starts the recovery program (without loading the full OS). It works something like this, but I have not tried it. I'm afraid it is too tied to Windows.

Comment: Pleas add this info to your original post ;-)

Answer (score 0):

That laptop of yours it pretty new so I bet it has UEFI? The firmware must detect the pressing of the button and then react to it. Easiest way that I could imagine for a manufacturer to implement something like this (once the key event is  caught) is to parse the boot entry list for a specific name or pattern, than boot it. Try to find a configuration option for this in your UEFI/BIOS. Then report here what you found.

Comment: I does have UEFI support, but I'm not using it (not yet). To be honest I don't even know if the OKR button works without UEFI, but on my previous laptop, which was also a Lenovo, there was an OKR button too and it did not support UEFI. I think I will have to reinstall my system and check out the official installer and behaviour.